# Error: "AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I got the error when requesting the page in http://localhost:56191/WebImages/index:

```
*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.*<br>
*AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:*

*WebApp.Controllers.WebImagesController.Index (WebApp)*<br>
*WebApp.Views.WebImagesController.Index (WebApp)*

*Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)*
```

Could this be because I ran due to update in the DB ?:

```
"Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Machinexx; Database=MyDBxx; Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force"
```

Comment: Please show us your `Controller` so that we can understand better what the problem is.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with your database, it's just as the error says, you have two controllers with the same name.

Comment: You routing is not well defined, Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283210/how-do-i-resolve-the-issue-the-request-matched-multiple-endpoints-in-net-core-w) hope that might help

Answer (score 0):

CodeCaster was right. I got another Controller with the same name inside the View folder, and I have no idea how it got there.