# Is there a way to make the framework to refer to the correct method based on the request body? (one item vs multiple items)

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I want to allow the client to sends posts requests of only one item and an collection of items without changing the methods route.

For Example:

Posting this body:

```
{
    "foo": "some value"
}
```

Should reach this method:

```
[HttpPost]        
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] MyPostRequest request = null)
```

Posting this body:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "some value"
    },
    {
        "foo": "some value"
    }   
]
```

Should reach this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<MyPostRequest> requests = null)
```

But requests are failed with:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
>   request matched multiple endpoints.

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59283210/6844481), I was able to see that [Route Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference) are the best option, but the question was about primitives types as parameters, and Route Constraints support only primitive types.

Is there a way to make the framework understand to refer to the correct signature based on the request's body (one item vs multiple items)? to change the methods name is the last resort.

Comment: Create custom model binder to get the single post item and add it to a collection and pass it to the second action. That way one action can handle both single item and collection

Comment: it seems like method with the collection is enough, one item might be also inside a collection, and no with no AmbiguousMatch. Is there a strong reason to keep second Method for holding only one entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some serious framework modifications, there won't be a way to accomplish this with routing alone; as you discovered, the closest built-in feature, route constraints, only works with primitives. If you absolutely need this functionality, I would go with Nkosi's suggestion in the comments: programmatically add the individual item to an `IEnumerable` before it reaches the controller method.

To avoid confusion about what the endpoint is doing, I would avoid this scenario altogether: either require an array or create a separate endpoint for that action. Each REST endpoint should refer to one type of resource and, even though the endpoint refers to a single model, **you are technically dealing with two types of resource: a collection and an object**.