# .net core request matched multiple endpoints exception on 2 different projects in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, routes, controller

I have a solution with 2 different .net core projects.

API: `localhost:7000`

example.API : `localhost: 7003`

both project has the same route for login '`/api/account/login`' (different port)

When i'm calling `localhost:7000/api/account/login` route from the client, i get the following exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> example.Controllers.AccountController.Signin (example.API)
>
> API.Controllers.AccountController.Login (API)

the projects are in different ports, and only one of them is running.
I also tried to unload the example.API project and I still have the problem.

only when I change the route of one of them is working.

does anyone have an idea why it's happening on 2 different projects?

Comment: This is not about two projects, the ambiguos exception is only in the one you are trying. I suggest you search for the error here in S.O.  This question needs more information and debug details to be answered.

Comment: I think you will find the answer in this topic:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283210/how-do-i-resolve-the-issue-the-request-matched-multiple-endpoints-in-net-core-w](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283210/how-do-i-resolve-the-issue-the-request-matched-multiple-endpoints-in-net-core-w)

Comment: The exception tells you which are colliding; modify one of them?

Comment: the answer refer above is when it's the same route in the same project.
in my case, if totally different projects, i don't understand why i need to modify them.

Comment: It seems you have include the other api inside another api, this makes one api running and it has the reference for another api. I suggest you could recheck your reference to make sure there is no reference for these two apis.