# How to Overload HttpPost Web API Method Based Json Datatype Properties

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, ambiguous

I am asked to implement a REST Web API to a specific route, where either of two different Json Datatypes may be posted.

This results in the following exception being thrown:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
```

Is there an Attribute that can be placed on the Web Methods, referencing Properties of the Json payloads so as to disambiguate the two possible Datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This was covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283210/how-do-i-resolve-the-issue-the-request-matched-multiple-endpoints-in-net-core-w) but I'll add a little bit.

It's not good API design to do that and goes against Swagger / OpenAPI specifications to do what you're asking.

The only way to do this with the same HTTP method (POST in your case) is to have one action that takes in both models. Check which one isn't null to then route to the correct method to handle that logic.

If you can get away with using a different HTTP verb you could technically do that and have two separate action methods (like POST and PUT), but you wouldn't be using them "correctly" and based on your question and need, I doubt you can do that anyway.

Comment: Thank you Zach Sexton.  I appreciate your answer; but let me clarify that this is an existing contract I am expected to implement.

I am not free to specify alternate routes for the Web methods, which are distinguished solely by their Json payloads.  The contract was likely developed years ago.

The question is not how to change the Legacy API; but how to leverage Asp.Net Core Web Methods.

To avoid the contortions of developing an artificial Union of the two Json Datatypes, I am looking for .Net Web API routing attribute to dispatch to the appropriate method - similar to a C# overload.

Comment: I will give this a try Zach.  We'll see how it goes.

Comment: I figured it was an existing contract. That's where having a single endpoint that then decides which method to run is probably your best bet. So either take in both objects and have the framework deserialize it (if that'll even work) or do it yourself with a string as Aman B said.

Comment: I was tempted to answer my own question; but I want to credit your answer for pushing me in the right direction. I disagree with the answer in your "This was covered here" citation, which begins by saying "What you're trying to do is impossible." (A risky response to any question.) I solved the Datatype union issue by making the simpler Json Datatype a subclass of the other. This complicates construction, many [Required] attributes, and Attribute-based Authentication. However, the basic strategy does indeed work. Aman B's idea requires too much reimplementation of Framework responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the request body as a string and then try to decide which type to deserialize in:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/mypath")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod()
{
  request.Body.Position = 0;

  var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);

  var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

  if(body.Contains("A))
  {
     var A = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(body);
  }
  else{
     var B = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(body);
  }
}
```

And add a middleware to enable request buffering:

```
app.Use(next => context => {
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    return next(context);
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://markb.uk/asp-net-core-read-raw-request-body-as-string.html)

Comment: Thank you Aman B.  You offer a plausible way forward.

I may be forced to adopt this approach.  I would rather not have go to that much trouble, of essentially implementing my own method dispatch; but I will if there is no alternative.

Essentially, I am looking for .Net Core to help by dispatching to the appropriate Web Method based on the Json Datatype.

While some may argue this is poor API design, overloaded methods are accepted in other programming contexts.