# How to solve multiple endpoints error in Web API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, http

I have multiple actions in the controller of my API. They mean to retrieve a bunch of data relating the models, So all of them are `[HttpGet]` type. How to resolve multiple endpoints error?

```
[HttpGet("{genreName}")]
        public IActionResult GetMoviesByGenre(string genreName)
        {
            var movies = _applicationDbContext.Movies.Where(m => m.Genres.Any(g => g.Name == genreName)).ToList();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(genreName))
               return NotFound();
            return Ok(movies);
        }
        [HttpGet("{directorName}")]
        public IActionResult GetMoviesOfADirector(string directorName)
        {
            var movies = _applicationDbContext.Movies.Where(m => m.Director.Name.Contains(directorName)).ToList();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(directorName))
                return NotFound();
            return Ok(movies);

        }
```

Comment: see: [How do I resolve the issue the request matched multiple endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283210/how-do-i-resolve-the-issue-the-request-matched-multiple-endpoints-in-net-core-w)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create two controllers like DirectorController.cs and GenreController and You can have endpoints like:

api/Director/{directorName}/Movies

api/Genre/{GenreName}/Movies