# API Versioning with .NET 7

Tags: .net-7.0, api-versioning, aspnet-api-versioning

I have migrated a .NET Core 2.1 application to .NET 7, I had API Versioning on that with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 2.3.0.

In the upgraded version the versioning does not work anymore, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints

I tried updating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning to 5.1.0 (which is deprecated) but that does not help.

Comment: Taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59283210/7450780)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by using Asp.Versioning.Mvc.

Comment: `Asp.Versioning.Mvc` is the correct package for MVC Core with controllers. _Minimal APIs_ should use `Asp.Versioning.Http`. Package details should be indicating the replacement packages and a link to the migration guide. Happy to provide additional information or context if needed.